# How to extract array of objects using interface

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular9, angular-json

I have an array of objects with large amount of data like
This is the example data but I am having large amount of key pair values

```
 [{ "id": 1, "name":"name1", age: 11,   "skl": {"name": "KK school"} },
    { "id": 2, "name":"name2", age: 12, "skl": {"name": "KK school"} },
    { "id": 3, "name":"name3", age: 13, "skl": {"name": "KK school"} },
    { "id": 4, "name":"name4", age: 14, "skl": {"name": "KK school"} } ]
```

I need only id and name and skl name like.

```
 [  { "id": 1, "name":"name1", "skl": {"name": "KK school"},
    { "id": 2, "name":"name2", "skl": {"name": "KK school"},
    { "id": 3, "name":"name3", "skl": {"name": "KK school"},
    { "id": 4, "name":"name4", "skl": {"name": "KK school"} ]
```

How to extract from these array of objects is there any possible solution

Comment: Like [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/N9jYVm) maybe?  I assume that `skl` also has a lot of properties.  Does that work for your use case or am I missing something?

Comment: Is there any way to do dynamically @jcalz

Comment: What do you mean by "dynamically"?  Please provide a [mre] with representative use cases for desired input/output so someone can help.

Answer (score 2):

You can either specify the properties you want to keep, or specify the properties you want to remove:

```js
const data = [
{ "id": 1, "name":"name1", age: 11, "skl": {"name": "KK school"} },
{ "id": 2, "name":"name2", age: 12, "skl": {"name": "KK school"} },
{ "id": 3, "name":"name3", age: 13, "skl": {"name": "KK school"} },
{ "id": 4, "name":"name4", age: 14, "skl": {"name": "KK school"} } ]

// choose what you want to retain:
console.log(data.map(({id, name, skl})=>({id, name, skl})))

// choose what you want to drop:
console.log(data.map(({age, ...other})=>other))

// dynamically:
console.log(data.map(i=>Object.fromEntries(Object.entries(i)
  .filter(([k])=>['id','name','skl'].includes(k)))))
```

Comment: Is there any way to do dynamically @Andrew Parks

Comment: @Gem I added to the answer - obviously you can pass in the array of properties you want to retain as a variable instead of hardcoding it

Answer (score 1):

Map through array and and extract age from reset array and returning rest shown
data without age key

```
  data.map(({age,...reset}) => reset) //map return a new array
```